# Converting Gas volume to Liquid Volume

Tags: fluid-dynamics, ideal-gas, weight, volume, inert-gases

For a test setup, I need to set CO2 flowrate as 130 L/h but I do not have a flow measuring device to set it. So I made one device as mentioned below.
Once I set the flowrate, I will remove containers/beaker and use the capillary tube to my test setup. (Ignore weight of beaker).

My query is, I was able to set 130 Liters/h equivalent flow rate using flow adjuster, but as my beaker gradient is having measure of liquid volume, is my device measuring a wrong flow rate?

[image: Flowmeter]

Comment: Note that beakers, Erlenmeyer flasks, dropping funnels and the like are _not_ volumetric instruments. They are not precisely calibrated, and their scales serve only as approximate guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an inverted measuring cylinder instead of a graduated beaker: it's more precise:

[image: Measuring cylinders]

Once the cylinder is near full, adjust its position so that the liquid meniscus *inside and outside* of the cylinder coincide exactly. That means pressure inside the cylinder is equal to atmospheric pressure. The ratio of volume collected and time elapsed is the *volumetric flow rate, at atmospheric pressure*.

Note also that $\text{CO}_2$ has some solubility in water, which could lead to a small error. To avoid this uses carbonated water, shaken until it releases no more bubbles (but will still be saturated with $\text{CO}_2)$.

Alternatively you may want to invest in a gas burette:

[image: Gas burette]